# Is it necessary to initialize the Facebook SDK on every call to my app?

Tags: php, facebook

I am new to writing apps on Facebook, I am using the "smash friends" sample in which it initializes the Facebook SDK.

The app contains a lot of PHP files. Do I need to initialize the SDK each and every time?

If not, how do I avoid it?

```
// Init the Facebook SDK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to use that FB code on every page, on which you intend on working with data grabbed directly from facebook api.